# converting an array into object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects:

```
const users: Person[] = [{name: 'Erich', age: 19}, {name: 'Johanna', age: 34}, {name: 'John', age: 14}];
```

Where

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
    name: string;
};
```

I need to convert it to the type NFCollection which looks so:

```
interface NFCollection {
    type: string;
    data: Person[];
}
```

The result should looks like this:

```
const nfCollection: NFCollection = {
    type: 'adults',
    data: [{name: 'Erich', age: 19}, {name: 'Johanna', age: 34}]
}
```

where the `data` includes only those persons whose age >= 18.

So I could start writing something like:

```
const nfCollection: NFCollection = users.filter(u => u.age >= 18); // something else should follow the chain?
```

but then I would like to convert it to the NFCollection type. How would I do that? Preferably in a memory efficient way, cos the array could be relatively big.

Comment: `const myNFCollection = { type: "adults", data: nfCollection };`...?

Comment: Yes, that's how I actually implemented it, but I thought I could easily do this in place, like within the same chain of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the filtered array as a property of a new object?

```
const nfCollection = {
    type: 'adults',
    data: users.filter(u => u.age >= 18)
};
```

Then `nfCollection` will have the same type as your `NFCollection` interface.

Comment: Yes, that's how I actually implemented it, but I thought I could easily do this in place, like within the same chain of functions.

Comment: A plain object literal definition is pretty easy to do in one place..? I suppose you *could* chain off of the `.filter` to construct the surrounding object (via `.reduce`), but it would look really really weird and wouldn't make sense `users.filter(u => u.age >= 18).reduce((_, __, ___, data) => ({ type: 'adults', data }))` plus tedious initial value typing

Comment: Yes, I agree, it looks weird. I will go with the proposed solution then. Thank you!